# import "hcaptcha_field" could not be resolved Django

Tags: django, django-forms, hcaptcha

I'm trying to add **hCaptcha** to my project but I can't get it to work, I've tried several versions of this library but I can't get it to work. Every time i tried importing `'hcaptcha_field'` or `'hcaptcha_fields'` it gives me the error `import "hcaptcha_field" could not be resolved Django`. Any solution?